# Save and displaying high score with variable across classes unity

Tags: variables, unity-game-engine

I need to get the variable score from my other class and set it as a UserPrefs key. it doesnt seem to be setting as i have a GUI label ingame which shos "None" if there is no UserPrefs key "Highscore".

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

using System.Threading;

public class Player : MonoBehaviour {

public Vector2 jumpForce = new Vector2(0, 300);
private Rigidbody2D rb2d;
Generator SwagScript;
GameObject generator;



// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    rb2d = gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    generator = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Generator");
    SwagScript = generator.GetComponent<Generator>();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    if (Input.GetKeyUp("space"))
    {
        rb2d.velocity = Vector2.zero;
        rb2d.AddForce(jumpForce);
    }

    Vector2 screenPosition = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(transform.position);
    if (screenPosition.y > Screen.height || screenPosition.y < 0)
    {
        Die();
    }
}

void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D other)
{
    Die();
}

void Die()
{
    if (PlayerPrefs.HasKey("HighScore"))
    {
        if (PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Highscore") < SwagScript.score)
        {
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("HighScore", SwagScript.score);
        }
        else
        {
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("HighScore", SwagScript.score);
        }
    }
    Application.LoadLevel(Application.loadedLevel);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you're creating the `Highscore` playerpref somewhere else, the `Die()` method won't never create it, since the `if (PlayerPrefs.HasKey("HighScore"))` will always return false.

Just remove that if.

Comment: Thanks mate I will do that!